# Kamailio - get first occurrence value of a param in a string

Tags: kamailio

I need to get the value of first tgrp param in this string using Kamailio :

```
$var(x) = <sip:xxxxxxxxx;tgrp=0001000;trunk-context=xx.xx.xx.xx@xx.xx.xx.xx:5060;transport=UDP;user=phone;tgrp=237>
```

I’m trying `$var(y) = $(var(x){param.value,tgrp});`  but it’s getting the last value of tgrp which is `237>`.

Noting that first tgrp is not always in the second index , some other parameters can be added to the string.

How to get the value of first occurrence of  tgrp param ?

Answer (score 0):

param.value string operations designed to work with unique params names.

You can loop over all params using **for** loop and checking **{param.name,index}**

Answer (score 0):

Try a solution based on xavp_params_explode():

- https://kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/pv.html#pv.f.xavp_params_explode

Something like:

```
xavp_params_explode("$(var(x){s.unbracket})", "x");
xdbg("$xavp(x=>tgrp[0])"); # <- print the value of first parameter tgrp
```

The index [0] can be omitted, without it first value being returned, but if you want the second param value, then use [1] as index.